# Italicize first line of /gll and second line of /glll

Tags: gb4e

When using gb4e, is it possible to apply \let\eachwordone=\itshape to every \gll, and \let\eachwordtwo=\itshape to every \glll? In other words, is it possible to only italicize the phrase in latin script, and not the non-latin original script (if there is any)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `etoolbox` package to include the font settings in the `\gll` and `\glll` commands instead of setting them globally. This package provides the command `\pretocmd` to modify a command such that the provided code is executed every time the command is called.

In the MWE below `\def` is used instead of `\let` for the double definition to prevent an error in the patching.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\gll}{\def\eachwordone{\itshape}\def\eachwordtwo{\normalfont}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\glll}{\let\eachwordtwo\itshape}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex
    \glll καλά Χριστούγεννα\\
    kala christouiena\\
    good christmas\\
    \glt `merry Christmas'
    \ex
    \gll fijne Kerstdagen\\
    nice {christmas days}\\
    \glt `merry Christmas'
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]